# Attach a property to a functional component wrapped with React.forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component wrapped with `React.forwardRef` and it so happens that it is a compound component as well.

I'm not sure how do I maintain

```
Form.Item  = FormItem;
```

while the Form component function being wrapped with `forwardRef`.

```
const Form = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => { return <form></form>});
```

Typescript gives me an error (rigthly) saying

> Property 'Item' does not exist on type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent>'.ts(2339)

Comment: Can you modify `Form` component? Or is it from a third-party library?

Comment: I can modify my Form component

Comment: What about this - https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/34757#issuecomment-488848720 ?

Comment: It does seems relevant. Thanks!

Comment: See [this repo](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/form/index.tsx) and settle your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just to make it more clear of the solution, as it's on an external site (Credits to original author [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/34757#issuecomment-488848720), and thank you @Antoan Elenkov)

```
export interface Props = {
   ...yourPropsHere;
};

export interface CompoundedComponent extends React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<Props & React.RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement>> {
   yourStaticFunctionOrSomethingLikeThat: () => void;
}

const Component = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>((props, ref) => (
    <input ref={ref} {...props} />
)) as CompoundedComponent;

Component.yourStaticFunctionOrSomethingLikeThat = () => {};
```

Comment: There's an even better answer now: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/34757#issuecomment-894053907

Comment: Lack of reasoning by the author on why it works makes me hesitant to believe its better.

Comment: Regardless of "why it works", I would be very surprised if that was unstable/undefined behavior, as it's pretty much just `Object.assign()`.

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/34757#issuecomment-894053907) from the same GH thread seems nicer to me:

```
const Form = React.forwardRef(function Form(...) {
  ...
})

const FormItem = React.forwardRef(...)

const FormNamespace = Object.assign(Form, {Item: FormItem})

export {FormNamespace as Form}
```